# Casting in a catch block (c++ throw and catch)

Tags: c++

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{};
class Derived: public Base {};

int main()
{
   Derived d;

   try{
        throw d;
   }
   catch(Base b){
        cout<<"Caught Base Exception";
   }
   catch(Derived d){
        cout<<"Caught Derived exception";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output is going to be `"Caught Base Exception"`.
As I udnerstand, catch blocks do not perform casting, and in order to use polymorphism we have to use deliver the thrown object by reference or as a pointer. So how come we do not witness slicing here? Why does the catch block recognise the thrown object as its base type when we did not delvier by reference/as a pointer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Yes it is https://godbolt.org/z/dT97Gd3K6

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik [yes, it will](https://ideone.com/sKc7ZT)

Comment: I get this warning: exception of type 'Derived' will be caught by earlier handler [-Wexceptions]
   catch(Derived d){
         ^

Comment: Compiler warnings are your first line of defense against programming mistakes. Turn them on and crank them up loud. Even if we eliminate the possibility of slicing, `catch(const Base &b)` and  `catch(const Derived & d)` we'll have the same problem.

Comment: also catch your exceptions by const &, e.g catch(const Base& b)

Comment: _"how come we do not witness slicing here?"_ What would "witness slicing" look like, in this example?  What were you looking for, that would indicate slicing?

Comment: Re: "catch blocks do not perform casting" -- no, only **casts** perform casting. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 5):

> So how come we do not witness slicing here?

You *do* observe slicing: `b` is a sliced-off base object from the original `d`, just like it would if you did `Base b = d;`.

As for why execution landed in the `catch(Base)`: that's not because the derived type wasn't recognized, but because execution lands into the *first* compatible `catch` block, as Clang eloquently warns:

```
<source>:18:10: warning: exception of type 'Derived' will be caught by earlier handler [-Wexceptions]
```

Swapping the `catch`es so that the `Derived` one has a chance to match outputs `Caught Derived exception`, as expected. Not that it would *still* be better to catch by reference, so as to not slice a potential  child of `Derived`.

Answer (score 1):

It matches the first in the list. Base will match Derived first because it's in order. Even the compiler warns you.

```
Source>:18:10: warning: exception of type 'Derived' will be caught by earlier handler [-Wexceptions]
   catch(Derived d){
         ^
<source>:15:10: note: for type 'Base'
   catch(Base b){
         ^
1 warning generated.
Compiler returned: 0
```

If you switch the order, everything compiles fine and the output is the expected

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{};
class Derived: public Base {};

int main()
{
   Derived d;

   try{
        throw d;
   }
   catch(Derived d){
        cout<<"Caught Derived exception";
   }
   catch(Base b){
        cout<<"Caught Base Exception";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Result

```
Program stdout
Caught Derived exception
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/sxj11Wcoq

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` blocks are tested in the order you coded them.  So, the `Base` catch will match the thrown `d` first (and yes, it does slice):

```cpp
int main()
{
   Derived d;

   try{
        throw d;
   }
   catch(Base b){ // <-- matches first, since d is derived from Base
        cout<<"Caught Base Exception";
   }
   catch(Derived d){
        cout<<"Caught Derived exception";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/sKc7ZT)

But, if you change the order of the `catch` blocks, the `Derived` catch will match the thrown `d` first (and not slice):

```cpp
int main()
{
   Derived d;

   try{
        throw d;
   }
   catch(Derived d){ // <-- matches first, since d is a Derived
        cout<<"Caught Derived exception";
   }
   catch(Base b){
        cout<<"Caught Base Exception";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/q1TpZA)

As such, it is best to code your `catch` blocks in order from most specific type to most generic type, ie derived types before base types (especially for `std` exceptions), `...` last, etc.